# Get the last occurance of the an object

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In my html page there is an option to add multiple "Resource Identity". When I add a new one, it it creates a new row with the following elements.

```
<tr>
<td width="150" valign="top">
<input type="hidden" name="expressions[0].checked"/>
<input type="hidden" value="B" name="expressions[0].expressionLabel"/>
<b>Resource Identity</b>
<input type="hidden" value="ResourceIdentity" name="expressions[0].parameterName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="ResourceIdentity" name="expressions[0].fieldName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="RF" name="expressions[0].fieldType"/>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="expressions[0].limitedValues"/>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="150" valign="top">
    <input type="hidden" name="expressions[1].checked"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="B" name="expressions[1].expressionLabel"/>
    <b>Resource Identity</b>
    <input type="hidden" value="ResourceIdentity" name="expressions[1].parameterName"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="ResourceIdentity" name="expressions[1].fieldName"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="RF" name="expressions[1].fieldType"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="expressions[1].limitedValues"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

How do I find the last occurrence of `<b>Resource Identity</b>`?
I am trying to find out the name above the  tag by using the below xpath, but it always evaluates to the find occurance as selenium scans the html from top to bottom.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//b[text() = 'Resource Identity']/preceding-sibling::input[1])).getAttribute("name").toString();
```

If there are multiple "Resource Identities", then how do I go to the last "Resource Identity" and find the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `last()`:

```
(//b[text() = 'Resource Identity']/preceding-sibling::input[1])[last()]
```

Comment: It still takes the first "Resource Identity" and not the last

Comment: @Leo ok, what about this `(//b[text() = 'Resource Identity']/preceding-sibling::input[1])[last()]`?

Comment: what if I want to get the 2nd 'Resource Identity'? How do I iterate?

Comment: @Leo then use `2` instead of `last()`.

Comment: my bad was trying out on the first way. Thanks

Comment: If you need to find more than one of them, you can do all the finding at once with findElement*s* with something like this `var listOfResorceIdentities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//b[text() = 'Resource Identity']/preceding-sibling::input[1]"))`. Then call them by index: 2nd item = listOfResourceIdentities[1] etc.